# Displaying URL link and replace the name of the variable using an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, url, replace

I don't really know what to do here, so I've come here for help. I've probably screwed this up when writing the code, but I tried to make it work. Basically I'm getting the user URL, and then using an array and preg_replace I want to see to replace the URL with a name for it.

I didn't explain that well, so here's an example of what I want it to do. So, let's say the user is on the home page. The URL is "/home.php", but I want to use an array and replace "/home.php" to say "Home".

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$links = array('/home.php', '/online.php');
$replace = array('Home', 'Online');

$last_seen = preg_replace($links, $replace, $url);

echo $last_seen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_replace` is perfect for replacing strings based on regular expression but in your situation `str_replace` will make a lot more sense.  Simply change `preg_replace` with `str_replace` like this:

```
$last_seen = str_replace($links, $replace, $url);
```

> **str_replace** — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string
>
> **Description**
>
> *mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )*
>
> **Source**
>
> http://php.net/str_replace